# Cannot access embedded resource in ASP.NET Core C# project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, embedded-resource

I am trying to set a stream equal to the text content of an embedded resource in my ASP.NET Core project. However, when debugging, the stream is continuously being set to null, and I assume that this is because of the fact that it cannot find this embedded resource to begin with.

I have set the file as an embedded resource by going to Properties > Build Action > Embedded Resource. And then I have also edited the projects `.csproj` file to include an item group which references the file to include:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Assets/loyalty-template.html">
    <LogicalName>Assets/Loyalty-template.html</LogicalName>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Where I set the stream:

```
string body;
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Assets/loyalty-template.html"))
   {
       TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
       body = tr.ReadToEnd();
   }
```

Am I referencing the embedded file correctly in the `GetManifestResourceStream`? Below is the file structure of my project where `loyalty-template.html` is situated:

[image]

Comment: Call GetManifestResourceNames to find out if the resource is there and under what name.

Comment: Isn't it much easier to just set the file as copy to output directory and then `File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine("Assets", "loyalty-template.html"));`?

Comment: It should be {ProjectDefaultNamespace}.Assets.{filename}, i.e. namespace + **dot** separated path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following path: [assembly name].[directory].[file name].

OR

Use GetManifestResourceNames with the file name and extension only:

```
string resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
.Single(str => str.EndsWith("loyalty-template.html"));
```

Comment: I have attempted this. However it still cannot find the resource? `var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("The-Food-Works-WebAPI.Assets.loyalty-template.html")`

Comment: This seems to be a fine path. Should be working.

Comment: Have you tried the following?
`string resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Single(str => str.EndsWith("loyalty-template.html"));`

Comment: Thank you so much. This did the trick. Please update your answer with this comment and ill upvote it!

Comment: Thank you @SeventhWarhawk for the upvote! My pleasure to help ;)